Architecting dynamic multi step forms using Nextjs and React hook form
I've spent most of today pouring over the React Hook Form documentation and watching a lot of videos, but find all of the examples to be really basic.
I'm trying to create a dynamic questionnaire builder allowing the user complete control over how many questions it includes, and the types of questions to ask (radio buttons, free text input & slider etc).
Ideally at the parent component level, which would be called CreateQuestionLayout - I would include templating such as dynamic title, based on slug, back links and generic styling:
export default function CreateQuestionLayout() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { questionId } = router.query;
    const clientId = router.query.clientId;
    const nextQuestionId = parseInt(questionId) + 1;

    return (
        <>
            <div className="page-max-width mx-auto">

                <div className="flex justify-between">
                    <h1 className="heading-1 mb-[10px]">
                        Question {questionId} <span className="text-[14px] font-normal text-black-60%">of 7</span>
                    </h1>
                </div>

                <CreateQuestion />

                <div className='flex flex-row gap-6 pb-20'>
                    <Link href={`/clients/${clientId}/create-new-survey/${nextQuestionId}`}>
                        <button className='button-primary'>
                            Create next question
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

The main purpose of this component is to render the CreateQuestion component, which is responsible for displaying a dropdown list, and utilising React hook form's watch API:
export default function CreateQuestion({ }) {
    const {
        register,
        watch,
    } = useForm({
        mode: "onBlur",
    });

    return (

        <div className="form-container mb-20">
            <div className="form-field">
                <SelectInput
                    label="Question type"
                    name="questionTypeId"
                    options={QUESTION_TYPES_DATA}
                    register={register}
                />
            </div>

            {watch("questionType") === '1' && (
                <TextInput />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

At this point <TextInput /> renders a custom form, with Yup validation and the usual React hook form behaviour.
However, this is where I get bewildered when it comes to best practise and how to proceed. I mentioned at the beginning that the user should be able to "Add another question" - this should only be possible when the TextInput form has been validated - but I'm unsure on how to propagate this event to my parent component (CreateQuestionLayout) which should handle re-routing, and state management for all added questions thus far.
export default function TextInput({ onSubmit }) {
  const validationSchema = useMemo(
    () =>
      Yup.object({
        title: Yup.string().required("Question title is required"),
      }),
    []
  );

  const {
    register,
    formState: { isValid, errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    mode: "onBlur",
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div className="form-field">
        <TextInput
          label="Question title"
          name="title"
          maxLength="50"
          register={register}
          errorMessage={errors.title?.message}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-field">
        <TextInput label="Placeholder text" name="description" maxLength="50" register={register} />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

How can I modify this code, so that:

The "Create next question" button in CreateQuestionLayout is only clickable once the TextInput form is valid
Which then dynamically routes to a new page, which has blank content

In future, I'll be aiming to manage state, so users can go back & edit previous answers too. Thanks in advance!
